# How should I implement a searchable model with no table in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Item` model that should behave in a similar way to an ActiveRecord object: it's a collection of records with an id and several columns, which I should be able to search. However, the data is static, and will be imported from a file downloaded from the web, so there is no need to store it in the database (I could, but it seems very inefficient, there's only 200 records or so). Furthermore, I need to establish associations with ActiveRecord models.

So the main question is: what would be the best way to implement this design-wise?

So far, I've found that I can do this

```
class Item
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :id, :name, :description, ...
end
```

which allows me to do some familiar things like creating objects and validation, but does not allow me to search, so I would have to do that manually. In fact, I would still need a place to store the collection (maybe a class variable or an in-memory store such as Redis?).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't overthink it. Just create an `ActiveRecord` model for it and import these 200 records - to have all the features you asked for (querying, associations).

Although you have 200 `static records`, it still make sense to persist them in DB. Number is not the issue here. (imagine many apps have a `roles` table which would only have two or three records).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use postgresql over redis for something simple (or if it's only going to be 200 records and you're really worried about size just use sqlite) like this where you want to keep relationships.  When you say static data do you mean the data never changes or only the location you pull from never changes?

Comment: The data itself doesn't change. It will get periodically updated on its original location but I'll pull it regularly, and this doesn't change anything inside the application.

Comment: To keep things straight forward and utilize the speed Rails provides for associations etc., even though the data-set is small and rarely updated I would map the file of data to a table in your database.  This allows you to then keep things simple everywhere else in your code and utilize the helper associations methods in your models.  Use postgresql if you plan on deploying to Heroku or else you can use the standard sqlite.  It's very easy to convert to postresql from sqlite if you've already built your app.